# How to turn on Eevvee rendering live preview?

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

How can I turn on Eevee rendering live preview in 3D view window?

The new Blender version has some interface changes, and in the Eevee rendering mode I can render an image, but I don't see live preview of the shading, Bloob and other effects in the 3D view.

[image]

How can I turn it on?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final release of Blender 2.8, you can find this toggle.

[image: Toggle for realtime rendering]

Toggle it, and in the renders tab choose Eevee:

[image: Choose Eevee in the drop down menu]

It should work now :D

Answer (score 3):

I found Rendered Shading in the Shading menu on the bottom of the 3D view window.

[image]

Comment: I cant find this menu. I downloaded Blender 2.8 Beta and there is no Shading menu like on your screenshot. Thanks for sharing that screenshot.